# History of the notation for substitution

Tags: lo.logic, ho.history-overview, notation, type-theory

One of the very common notations for syntactic substitution is $[\ /\ ]$.
However, there seems to be an inconsistency in the literature about its usage.

- Many write $[t/x]$ for "substitute $t$ for $x$" (Girard, Buss, ...).
- Others use $[x/t]$ for "replace $x$ with $t$" (van Dalen, Troelstra, Martin-Löf, ...).

I am wondering about the history of this notation. 
In particular, 
who was the first person to use this notation for 
syntactic substitution in logic?

Comment: In case you are not only interested in _precisely_ this notation, let me mention that Bourbaki introduces $(B|x)A$ in a draft of E.I, dating from 1951 (état 6, page 3) and keeps it since then. The preceding version uses the $(Sub$ $x|B)A$ (état 5, page 2).

Comment: @Fred, yes, I am aware of other notions, including $[x := t]$ and $[x \mapsto t]$. I am more interested in figuring out that how this particular notation was originally used. I have searched a bit to see if Russel and Whitehead or Hilbert or Frege have used it but I haven't find any evidence so far.

Comment: A similar notation is for valuations, used in defining the satisfaction relation. In this case, Vaught and other Berkeley logicians (presumably also Tarski) used $M\models\varphi[{x\atop a}]$, where $x$ is a variable symbol and $a$ is an object in $M$.

Comment: When I was taught, we used $\int_t^x\varphi$ to denote this substitution. What @Joel describes was used to describe assignments of values.

Comment: It seem a more common and older notation for dealing with substitution is the function notations: first indicate the formula with its variables like $\varphi(x)$ and then the result of substituting $t$ for $x$ is represented as $\varphi(t)$ without a symbol for the substitution _operation_.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Some early examples of the form $[t/x]$ are due to Haskell Curry.

See:

- Haskell Curry & Robert Feys & William Craig, [Combinatory Logic. Volume I](https://books.google.it/books/about/Combinatory_Logic.html?id=avrcMwEACAAJ&redir_esc=y) (1958), page 54:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be obs and let $x$ be a variable; it is required to define the ob $b^*$ which is obtained by substitution of $a$ for $x$ in $b$. [...]
>
> We shall adopt the notation
>
> $$[a/x] b$$
>
> for the $b^*$ so defined.

See also:

- Haskell Curry, [Foundations of Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=27dkTJFrLZIC&pg=PA114) (1963), page 114:

> In general, if there are no bound variables to restrict the substitution, we define the result of substituting an ob $M$ for $x$, symbolized as
>
> $$[M/x]X$$
>
> as that ob $X^*$ whose construction is obtained from a construction of $X$ by 
>   replacing subconstructions leading to $x$ by constructions of $M$.

---

For $[x/t]$, see :

- Alfred Tarski, [A simplified formalization of predicate logic with identity](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01972461), (1964) page 62:

> Let $\varphi(\alpha/\beta)$ be the formula obtained from the formula $\varphi$ by proper substitution of the variable $\beta$ for the variable $\alpha$.

We may suppose that Tarski has "simplified" the notation used by Kurt Gödel in [1930](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&pg=PA600), with

> $$\text {Subst } a (^v_b)$$

and Alonzo Church in [1932](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968337?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (and see: [The calculi of lambda-conversion](https://books.google.it/books?id=v6_SCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA9) (1941)):

> $$S^x_NM|.$$

A "variant" of Tarski's form is used by e.g. Enderton, with: $\alpha_t^x$.

Answer (score 9):

You will not find any substitution notation in Frege, altough he does have a rule of substitution in his *Grundgesetze*-system (namely, rule 9 of its § 48). For an early example of substition notation in logic, see Russell's paper *Mathematical Logic as based on the Theory of Types* (1908). For instance, on its page 238 you can read:

> If *p* is a proposition, and *a* a constituent of *p*, let "*p/a;x*" denote the proposition which results from substituting *x* for *a* wherever *a* occurs in *p*.

Gödel, as cited above by Mauro Allegranza, probably takes his notation from Von Neumann, who in his remarkable paper *Zur Hilbertschen Beweistheorie* (1927) writes

$$\mathrm{Subst}\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
x_p \\ b
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)a$$

Von Neumann may in turn have taken this notation from his fellow countryman Julius König's book *Neue Grundlagen der Logik, Arithmetik, und Mengenlehre* (1904). König explains his substitution notation,

$$\mathrm{S}\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
x \\ V
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)F$$

on pages 92ff.

The source of König's notation may be the notation exemplified by

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1&2&3&4 \\
 2&4&1&3
\end{pmatrix} $$

for what are nowadays usually called permutations, but which Cauchy, who introduced this notation in a paper from 1815, called, precisely, substitutions.

Substitution notation is of course also used in the calculus. Thus, Cauchy in his *Cours d'Analyse* (1821) suggests

$$\int f(x)\,dx\,\bigl[\begin{smallmatrix}
x=x_0 \\ x=X
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr]$$

as one possible notation for the integral. (The now standard notation $\int_{x_0}^Xf(x)\,dx$ was introduced by Fourier.) The relevant extracts from Cauchy's texts can be found, in the original and translated, in Jacqueline Stedall's source book *Mathematics Emerging*.

I should note that I have learned most of the information reported here from Per Martin-Löf (the reference to König is due to Göran Sundholm).

Answer (score 4):

(To the title question, and @AnstenKlev’s answer:)

**Sarrus ([1848](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5516487n/f14))** introduced maybe the earliest *signe de substitution* : $\style{font-family:sans-serif;font-style:italic}1\,^t_x$.